# Android backup database to Google drive NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-drive-api

In my android app I have a simple database backup/restore connected with Google drive.

Last days I noticed this error with 2 users of my app:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.api.services.drive.model.File.getId()' on a null object reference at myapp.DriveServiceHelper.lambda$createFilePDF$1$myapp-DriveServiceHelper(DriveServiceHelper.java:46)
```

This is a part of the code.

```
public Task<String> createFilePDF (File filePath)
{
    final TaskCompletionSource<String> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
    service.execute(
            () -> {
                com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetaData = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
                fileMetaData.setName("myappdb.db");
                FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/vnd.sqlite3", filePath);
                com.google.api.services.drive.model.File myFile = null;

                try {
                    myFile = mDriveService.files().create(fileMetaData, mediaContent).execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                assert myFile != null;
                String finalResult =  myFile.getId();
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> tcs.setResult(finalResult), 1500);
            });

    return tcs.getTask();
}
```

I know what Nullpointer is, but can't resolve why. I tried the backup on two different devices on the same latest version of the app and everything works fine.

The problem is in line: `String finalResult =  myFile.getId();`

For some reason the `getId()` is null. But if the code stops on this line, it means, it already created the file on Google drive for user in the try/catch before:  `myFile = mDriveService.files().create(fileMetaData, mediaContent).execute();`

Not sure why that file has no ID or why it can't get it only for 2 users.

For both users the issue is on OnePlus8Pro and Android 11.

The only thing I did in the latest version, was that I removed `READ_EXTERNAL_PERMISSIONS` from manifest, as for Android 13 it is deprecated, but I don't think it is related to reading from Google drive, as on my device the backup and restore works on Android 11 and 12.

Maybe I should add a condition there:

```
 if (myFile.getId()!= null) {
      String finalResult =  myFile.getId();
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> tcs.setResult(finalResult), 1500);
    }
```

but what if it will be null again for some users, how to fix it.

And additional code - this is from where the `createFilePDF` method is called. You can see, if no DB file exists, it doesn't allow to backup, so the DB file existed for the user in that time:

```
 public void uploadfile ()
    {
        String Path = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("myappdb.db").getAbsolutePath();
        File filePath = new File( Path);

        if(!filePath.exists()) {progressDialog.cancel();showMsgSnack(getString(R.string.emptylist));}
        else {
            driveServiceHelper.createFilePDF(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(s -> {
                progressDialog.cancel();
                showMsgSnack(getString(R.string.uploadok));
            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        progressDialog.cancel();
                        showMsgSnack(getString(R.string.uploaderror));
                    });
        }
    }
```